# What does this mathematical representation mean?

Tags: probability

[image]

This is about Monte-Carlo confidence intervals. What does the content in the red rectangle mean exactly?

Comment: if $E_1$ etc has a value, $\min_i E_i$ is the minimum of the six values.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Thank you Mauro. What's the  "i" below the "min" ?

Comment: In the text it is used "the median for each $E_i$". It is the same : if we have $E_1, \ldots , E_6$, we can abbreviate it as $E_i$ (implicitly : $i=1, \ldots, 6$).

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA THANKS.